# GNU grep, backreferences and wildcards

Tags: grep, wildcard, backreference

Using `grep` (GNU grep 3.3) to search for all words with three consecutive double-letters (resulting in "bookkeeper"):

```
grep -E "((.)\2){3}" /usr/share/dict/american-english
```

Changing this to search for words with three double-letters, each of them followed by the letter "i" (resulting in "Mississippi"):

```
grep -E "((.)\2i){3}" /usr/share/dict/american-english
```

Changing this to search for words with three double-letters, each of them followed by any single letter (with a couple of results):

```
grep -E "((.)\2.){3}" /usr/share/dict/american-english
```

Changing this to search for words with three double-letters separated by an optional, single letter (even more results):

```
grep -E "((.)\2.?){3}" /usr/share/dict/american-english
```

Now, finally, my original task: Search for all words containing three double-letters:

```
grep -E "((.)\2.*){3}" /usr/share/dict/american-english
```

But this results in an empty set. Why? How can `.?` match something `.*` does not?

Comment: Ig it is GNU grep, just use the PCRE engine, `grep -P '((.)\2.*){3}'`

Comment: POSIX regex is just not able to deal with so much regex complexity in the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POSIX regex engine does not handle patterns with back-references well, [matching back references is an NP complete problem](http://perl.plover.com/NPC/NPC-3SAT.html) might provide some hints on why it is that difficult.

Since you are using a GNU `grep`, the problem is easily solved with the PCRE engine,

```bash
grep -P '((.)\2.*){3}' file
```

since the PCRE engine can handle back-references in a more efficient way than the POSIX regex engine.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/3J67Lk).

Comment: Hm, I'd consider "not well" to be a bug in this case. If it took (much) time: that's how it is. Returning a wrong result should not happen.